# Yet another string splitting in java

Tags: java, regex, split

My question is about splitting a string using multiple delimiters in a Java application.

I know you can split using the not so fancy StringTokenizer or use the preferred split method. I tried to use it:

```
String strToSplit = "Hello deer. Nice to meet you!How are you today? Don't you go missing on me, okay?";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strToSplit.split("\\s+|\\.|\\,|\\?|\\!")));
```

Okay, here's the deal. For simplicity we want to split the upper string along those nice delimiters in the regex with possible multiple spaces. So, one - that would be pointing towards myself - would expect to see something like the following:

```
[Hello, deer, Nice, to, meet, you, How, are, you, today, Don't, you, go, missing, on, me, okay]
```

And actually this is the exact reason I directly asked **!!!NOT!!!** to mark the question as duplicate, because this is the exact solution from all the other questions that exists here. Well, while it definietly Works in some cases not in the upper case... yeah I know it's bad. An accepted solution like 100+ times and it's flawed. Because this solution bleeds in the case when multiple delimiters are following eachother. So the upper mentioned - let me repeat myself 100+ accepted solution - fives an incorrect output:

```
[Hello, deer, , Nice, to, meet, you, How, are, you, today, , Don't, you, go, missing, on, me, , okay]
```

A Matched dot `.` character followed by a space    breaks the above. While there is a case to match them when one follows the other or the other way around this just doesn't work which gives a string with a length of 1 and it's only character begin a space  .

Now to my actual question: Since I'm horrible at regular expressions, could someone with a better knowledge than myself show me a scheme that can be used for this "complicated" case, that actually Works?

Comment: Like [this](https://ideone.com/FeMXDX)? I believe you just want to put all the delimiters into a character class and add a `+` quantifier to make it match 1 or more characters.

Comment: Could you more directly, before your tests, show: what is your input, what is your requirements, what do you expect ? What works, and what doesnt ?

Comment: @stribizhev Exactly like that. I don't consider this "special" requirement tho, this is splitting by multiple delims. Who says 2 different delims couldn't follow eachother? Anyway could you put that in an answer so I can accept that right away? Thanks!
For the rest guys: Read the question it contains all the information you're asking for.

Comment: I will now post it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To match 1 or more several symbols in 1 go*, you can use a **[character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)** and apply [`+` quantifier](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet) to make it match 1 or more characters.

```
String strToSplit = "Hello deer. Nice to meet you!How are you today? Don't you go missing on me, okay?";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strToSplit.split("[\\s.,?!]+")));
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/FeMXDX)

Output:

```
[Hello, deer, Nice, to, meet, you, How, are, you, today, Don't, you, go, missing, on, me, okay]
```

The main point is that the `"\\s+|\\.|\\,|\\?|\\!"` only matches 1 or more whitespaces (with `\s+`) and only **single**  `.`, `,`, `?`, or `!`.

Comment: Another good resource I can recommend is [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kQ2bX9/1). You can check regexps there first and see how the text is matched in real time.

Comment: for the regex link, +1

Comment: @user3437460: Just for Java, it might not be the best online regex tester since it does not fully support its syntax, but for simple regexps it really is sufficient. For proper Java regex testing, I can recommend [`RegexPlanet`](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) (provides some advanced means to see how the pattern behaves with common Java regex methods, shows escaping, etc.) and [`OCPSoft Visual Regex Tester`](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/) (provides real-time matching).

Answer (score 1):

Since you split on a dot and on a space, things go wrong when a dot is followed by a space. In such cases, you get an empty string in your resulting array. Which is expected of course: you split on both, but there's nothing in between.

Try something like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strToSplit.split("(\\s+|\\.|\\,|\\?|\\!)+")));
```

Or the equivalent:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strToSplit.split("[\\s.,?!]+")));
```

Comment: You posted my suggestion

Comment: I was writing my answer before I saw your suggestion. Personally, I think my answer is better: I explain why the OP sees what s/he sees, and give 1 solution close to his/her own attempt, and a more compact solution.  So I will let this answer stand. EDIT at least, my asnwer was better before you trickled in your edits... :)

Comment: Yeah guys, I'm glad both of you understood my problems cleary and fást. If I could I'd give the points to the both of you because both your solutions are correct. So yeah, I really appreciate it! Since however I can only give the points to one of you, I think it's the more appropriate to give it to the one who showed my misery missing '+' sign first which was stribizhev. But really I I could I'd give to both of you.

Comment: `(\\s+|\\.|\\,|\\?|\\!)+` involves too much backtracking, I'd rather you delete it.

Comment: @Displayname sure, no problem. Multiple correct answers can never hurt. Perhaps some future visitor benefits.

Comment: For the backtracking to have any impact on the performance, the target string would have to be rather large. And if the app would make a network call or database call, it wouldn't even matter. Simply stating that `(\\s+|\\.|\\,|\\?|\\!)+` involves too much back tracking (without any context) is IMO nonsense.